# Combined async results with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, rxjs, react-redux

I'm working on my first React / Redux app, and I've now reached the first non-trivial problem.

App data (quite a lot of it) is loaded asynchronously from the server on page load, using a default parameter. It's then filtered further on the client side. Both the parameter for the initial data load and the filters may be altered by the user.

One problem I might have is stale data being returned from the initial data load, should the user switch the parameter before it is returned. Another is managing the chain of events in an idiomatic Redux manner.

I'm sure I could manually cancel previous callbacks, but I'm really looking for a more imperative approach.

I would normally solve this sort of problem using RX. Would this be sensible here? In which case, where should my RX code sit?

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a library called [Redux-Observable,](https://redux-observable.js.org/) which allows you to view Redux events as event streams, and perform complex async operations as a result.  It fits the bill perfectly.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AslncyG8whg) got me started

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable solution so far is the usage of [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) library. It takes care of the side effects in an expressive, easy to test [declarative way](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html) (not a rxjs solution).

In your situation is necessary to use the `takeLatest()` effect, which makes sure that only latest request is handled:

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* watchFetchData() {
  yield takeLatest('FETCH_REQUESTED', fetchData)
}

export function* fetchData(action) {
   try {
      const data = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.url)
      yield put({type: "FETCH_SUCCEEDED", data})
   } catch (error) {
      yield put({type: "FETCH_FAILED", error})
   }
}
```

`'FETCH_REQUESTED'` is the action type sent from an action creator. `takeLatest()` makes sure to handle only the latest action, and you get the result only from the latest fetch request.

If you use a fetch library like axios, you can [force the cancellation](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/651#issuecomment-262375964) of unecessary ajax requests.

More details about [saga helpers](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I evaluated red-saga and also react-observable, and decided to go with the latter